# Find item in list by type

Tags: python, list, search, types

I have a list that can contain several elements of different types.
I need to check if in this list there is one or more elements of a specific type and get its index.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, myobj, 4, 5]
```

I can achieve this goal by simply iterate over my list and check the type of each element:

```
for i, v in enumerate(l):
  if type(v) == Mytype:
    return i
```

Is there a more pythonic way to accomplish the same result?

Comment: Do you need the indices of all elements of that type, or just the first one?

Comment: @BrenBarn In my specific case I need only the first one, but a "general" solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a comprehension or a generator exp - however that would mean you have to go through the entire list to see if there is atleast one. Your method is more efficient IMO.

Comment: `if is instance(v, Mytype):` would be better, but otherwise this seems fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
return next(i for i, v in enumerate(l) if isinstance(v, Mytype)):
```

The advantage of this solution is that it is lazy like your current one: it will only check as many items as are necessary.

Also, I used `isinstance(v, Mytype)` instead of `type(v) == Mytype` because it is the preferred method of typechecking in Python. See [PEP 0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Finally, it should be noted that this solution will raise a `StopIteration` exception if the desired item is not found.  You can catch this with a try/except, or you can specify a default value to return:

```
return next((i for i, v in enumerate(l) if isinstance(v, Mytype)), None):
```

In this case, `None` will be returned if nothing is found.

Comment: And how can I get the index of the element in this way?

Comment: @Nick - I'm sorry, I misread your question.  Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension.

Get all elements of type string:

```
b = [x for x in a if isinstance(x,str)]
```

Get all indexes of elements of type string:

```
b = [x[0] for x in enumerate(a) if isinstance(x[1],str)]
```